# Xcode I want to pass a variable into the method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, methods

```
-(void)end{
NSLog(@"End Called");

}    

UIImage *bPin = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BluePin.png"];
        UIImage *gPin = [UIImage imageNamed:@"GreenPin.png"];
        UIImage *rPin = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RedPin.png"];
        UIImage *yPin = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YellowPin.png"];
        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,bPin.size.width,bPin.size.height)];
        image.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 bPin,
                                 rPin,
                                 gPin,
                                 yPin,
                                 nil];

        image.animationRepeatCount = 0;
        image.animationDuration = 1.0;
        [image startAnimating];

        [image setFrame: CGRectMake(point.x-(image.bounds.size.width/2), point.y-(image.bounds.size.width/2), image.bounds.size.width, image.bounds.size.height)];
        [self.view addSubview: image];



        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 delay:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear  animations:^{
            [image setAlpha:0.0];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [image removeFromSuperview];

        }];
```

I want to send image to the void end method how do I do that though? I need to end it there in order to animate the certain image... just how do i send it?????

Comment: You are not calling `end` from anywhere in your code, so it is hard to answer your question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not seeing what the problem is (nor how this question is related to Xcode), why not simply

```
- (void)end:(UIImage *)img
{
    // do stuff
}
```

and call it like

```
[self end:imageView.image];
```

?

Comment: I will do stuff in the void end but I dont know how to send the object image into the void end???? and     [self end:imageView.image]; didnt work

Comment: @userxxx you don't "send an object". If you don't even know how to call a method with parameters, you should probably be reading an Objective-C turorial instead of being deep in the development of an iOS app... **I just explained to you how to do all this...**

Answer (score 0):

Update your end method to be like this

```
- (void) end:(UIImageView *)imageToAnimate {
     NSLog(@"end called");
}
```

Then call it:

```
[self end:image];
```

Comment: and to call the method but don't send it anything do [self end:nil]; ? I need to call it in another method too but send it nothing

Comment: yes, you can send `nil` if you don't want to pass any object.

Comment: ok how would I pass something into -(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{ [self touchesCancelled:image]; doesnt work